# Function equalizer = gst_element_factory_make ("equalizer-3bands", NULL); return NULL

Tags: gstreamer

In Android Studio for Windows I created RTSP Player using project of Ognyan Tonchev  - https://github.com/otonchev/rtspviewersf.

I tried change pipeline using technology, described in Playback tutorial 7: Custom playbin sinks.

But:

```
function equalizer = gst_element_factory_make ("equalizer-3bands", NULL);
```

returns `NULL` with message:

```
no such element factory "equalizer-3bands"!
```

I read, that for Linux in this case it is necessary to install gstreamer0.10-plugins-good, or similar.

Is it true for Windows? And How can I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you mean GStreamer 1.0 and not 0.10.. The latter has not received any support for years.

When you have installed your GStreamer version on Windows via the official binary release installer from them - There is an option when installing what to install. E.g. "Install" and "Full Install". I recommend to select "Full Install" if you are unsure if your plugins you want to part of the regular install.

Comment: Thank you Florian Zwoch for your interest.
I installed the full version. And I understood that plugins connected in Android.mk. 
I just don't know where to find the list of variables for the corresponding plugins. In particular, what variable do I need to add to connect the “xvimagesink” plugin?
Trying to invent a variable $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_XVIMAGESINK)
was unsuccessful - gstelementfactory.c:456: gst_element_factory_make no such element factory "xvimagesink"!

Comment: Basically `gst-inspect-1.0` is the tool that lists all available plugins. And `gst-inspect-1.0 <plugin>` lists details about a specific plugin. If you don't have the tool available on your platform I suggest looking at it's source code how to get access to all this information programmatically.